# react query useMutation typescript getting error on args

Tags: typescript, react-query

I try to use react query useMutation with typescript and still getting error on args when i want to trigger my function. I'm new in typescript i try to googled, and on stackoverflow also give me infomation how to type useMutation. But i still do not understand why i'm getting error `TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Login'`

```
interface Login{
    username: string,
    password: string

}

interface Token{
    access_token: string,
    refresh_token: string
}


const loginToServer = useMutation<Token, unknown,  Login>(newLogin => axios.post(url, {
        username: username,
        password: password
    }),
)


<Button label="Sign In" icon="pi pi-user" 
       onClick={() => loginToServer.mutate(username, password)}/> // revieve an error TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Login'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass your variables to `mutate` as an object of shape `Login`, so wrap your `username, password` in `{` and `}`).

```
<Button label="Sign In" icon="pi pi-user" 
       onClick={() => loginToServer.mutate( { username, password } )}/>
```